# Adding tool tip for a button based on some condition in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on an app where I have to disable a button, based on some condition. when it is disabled it is showing stop symbol but requirement says it needs to show a tooltip with a reason  "why it is disabled" ...

```
 = select_tag "admin_role", options_for_select( admin_options, default_admin_role(@user) ), class: 'form-control search_text' , disabled: should_be_disabled?(@user, "main_administrator") , include_blank: true 

 def should_be_disabled?(user, role_name)
    return true if user.admin?(@site) && role_name != "main_administrator" && role_name =~ /administrator/
    return true if user.temporary? && role_name =~ /administrator/
  end
```

there is a disabled attribute when it is true it shows a stop symbol when that condition gives true. instead of that stop symbol, I want to show a tooltip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stop symbol is the cursor effect.
If you want to replace it with a tooltip.

```
- if should_be_disabled?(user, role_name)
  # put tooltip code here, you can use zurb-foundation or bootstrap to easily create a tooltip
- else
  = select_tag "admin_role", options_for_select( admin_options, default_admin_role(@user) ), class: 'form-control search_text' , include_blank: true
```

Comment: i added                  = select_tag "admin_role", options_for_select( admin_options, default_admin_role(@user) ), disabled: true, include_blank: true ,  class: 'form-control search_text' ,data_toggle: "tooltip", data_placement: "left", title:"Administrator roles can only be assigned to registered users"
and Js javascript:
  $(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
  });

Comment: Hi @gangothri, congratulations, it looks like you made it.